# Copy full name from a table and insert first name and last name into new table separate columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I'm using SQL Server and I have a column called "Full Name" in one table. I want to separate the first and last name and put those in their own columns in another table.

```
TABLE 1
**Full Name** (all one columns)   
Joe Mamma    
Fred Flintstone  
Frank ford   
John Doe
```

```
TABLE 2
**First Name**( Col1)    **Last Name**  (Column2) 
Joe                         Mamma    
Fred                     Flintstone  
Frank                       ford   
John                         Doe
```

Here is the code that I used to separate the names:

```
alter table mytable
add 
    first_name as LEFT(Full_Name,CHARINDEX(' ',Full_Name )-1)
  , Last_Name as RIGHT(Full_Name, LEN(Full_Name)- CHARINDEX(' ', Full_Name))

select * from mytable
```

But that creates separate columns in the original table. Is there a way that I could just copy without creating columns?

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and a database tag.  Be explicit on how to handle middle names, multi-part first and last names, and suffixes.

Comment: Don't copy data around between tables.

Comment: Great test data: Malcolm McDowell, Conan O'Brien, Carl van der Walt and Jonathan Rhys-Davies.

Comment: But WHY do you want to duplicate information? That is generally a **bad** thing to do. You have all the values in one table - there should be no reason to copy them into another without a good reason.

Comment: Desired results are shown as "Table 2" No milddle names, first part info or suffixes required at this time. Thank you !

Comment: @SMor I will have a custom report that gets sent out weekly. All data comes from one datasource  just not in the right format.  so I wanted to take the general data from the datasource and link it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not alter the original table.

assuming that you have a table created already (lets call it newtable), that has columns first_name and last_name:

```
SELECT 
    LEFT(Full_Name,CHARINDEX(' ',mytable.Full_Name )-1) as first_name,
    RIGHT(Full_Name, LEN(mytable.Full_Name)- CHARINDEX(' ', mytable.Full_Name)) as last_name
INTO newtable 
FROM mytable  
GO
```

**EDIT:**
If the table you want to fill the first name and last name already exists, you can use an update statement:

**EDIT**  Corrected syntax to align with T-SQL as oposed to other open source engines

```
UPDATE
    newtable
SET
    newtable.first_name = LEFT(Full_Name,CHARINDEX(' ',mytable.Full_Name )-1),
    newtable.last_name = RIGHT(Full_Name, LEN(mytable.Full_Name)- CHARINDEX(' ', mytable.Full_Name))
FROM
    mytable
INNER JOIN
    newtable
ON 
    mytable.full_name = newtable.full_name;
```

This requires that there is a key (person_id in this case) that associates both tables, so the update statement can match which rows does it need to update from new_table based on the rows from mytable.

Comment: Hi Thanks! I am getting an error saying that the name table already exists, is there away to alter the table rather than make a new table ?

Comment: You can do an update statement. Just edited the solution to give one

Comment: Darn, my participant id key that id be filtering on has null values in it! Is there a way to group on anything else? thanks for all your help!

Comment: if new table has the fileds full_name, first_name and last_name, you can do this in 2 steps:
1) Insert all full names from mytable to newtable. Leave first_name and last_name empty.
2) use the update mentioned in the solution, but instead of person_id, as key, use full_name. I also caught an error in the solution, that i will fix shortl.

Comment: This is not valid syntax for UPDATE in SQL Server

Comment: That is correct. Just edited the main solution for an update statement that aligns with T-SQL instead of other open source engines.

Answer (score 0):

You could use your existing code but just do a `SELECT INTO` to create a new table.

```
SELECT LEFT(Full_Name,CHARINDEX(' ',Full_Name )-1) AS first_name
        ,RIGHT(Full_Name, LEN(Full_Name)- CHARINDEX(' ', Full_Name)) AS Last_Name
INTO table2
from mytable
```